# How can I get my mysqld-swamped CPU under control?

Tags: mysql, cpu-load

I was AFK for about 24 hours and came back to find `gnome-system-monitor` saying all four CPU cores on my laptop were running at full throttle. `mysqld` is taking up more than one full core; when I tried to end the process, it restarted with a new PID. Then there's `ksoftirqd/0-3`, which apparently has something to do with interrupts, but I can't tell from Google what I'm supposed to *do* with those four particular processes. They're taking up a quarter or more of my processor cycles. Then there's Chrome, but I can probably handle that on my own -- how do I cool down the other processes giving me problems?

Comment: No answer, same problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in the kernel that causes a failure because of the "leap second" that happened on June 30.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1020285

Answer (score 2):

Here is a description of the problem and the fix: http://blog.mozilla.org/it/2012/06/30/mysql-and-the-leap-second-high-cpu-and-the-fix/

To solve the problem, run

```
date -s "`date`" && touch /tmp/leapsecond_2012_06_30
```

(Those are backticks inside double-quotes. Backtick <kbd>`</kbd> is the un-<kbd>shift</kbd>ed version of the <kbd>~</kbd> key on my keyboard: below <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> on my keyboard, but above <kbd>Tab</kbd>. So not quite all the way to the upper left corner.)

I don't know why the second part (I guess to keep a record of it being executed?) but if Mozilla says to do it, it's probably right.

[This source](http://blog.windfluechter.net/content/blog/2012/07/01/1481-100-cpu-load-due-leap-second) omits the `touch` part.